# Deleting spaces problem in NASM x86 Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am working on a code which will remove spaces from given string. But I encountered segmentation fault.

```
section .text
extern printf
global  remove_spaces

remove_spaces:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

    mov eax, [esp+8]
    mov edx, eax
rs_loop:    
    mov cl, [edx]
    cmp cl, 0
    je  rs_exit

    inc edx

    cmp cl, ' '
    je  rs_loop

    mov [eax], cl
    inc eax 
    jmp rs_loop

rs_exit:
    push DWORD [esp + 8]
    push DWORD format2
    call printf

exit:
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret


section .data       
    format:         DB "** a=%s\ **",   00ah,       0
    format2:        DB "d* a=%d\ *d",   00ah 
    format3:        DB "type is:%d ",   00ah,       0
```

I have my string's address in eax.
Then I copy it to edx and start to loop through it.
If character is not a space I try to add it to the string in eax. But when I add this line to code:

```
 mov [eax], bl
```

I have an segmentation error.

Here is my c code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

extern  char* remove_spaces(char *a);

    int main(){
      char *a = "Remove spaces  . ";
      char *spaces_removed = remove_spaces(a);
      //printf("\n%s", spaces_removed);
      return 0;
    }
```

I checked if my string is correct. I wonder if I am miss-using the instruction 
     mov [eax], bl
Because everything seems fine until there.
What should I do?
PS: question and code is edited as @Jester suggested.

And here is my make file and bash script :

```
CC=g++
ASMBIN=nasm

all : asm cc link
asm : 
    $(ASMBIN) -o food.o -f elf -g -l remove_spaces.lst remove_spaces.asm
cc :
    $(CC) -m32 -c -g -O0 main.cpp &> errors.txt
link :
    $(CC) -m32 -g -o test main.o remove_spaces.o
clean :
    rm *.o
    rm test
    rm errors.txt   
    rm remove_spaces.lst
```

and

```
rm -f main
rm -f remove_spaces.o
nasm -f elf -o remove_spaces.o remove_spaces.asm
gcc -m32 -o main main.c remove_spaces.o
./main
```

Comment: What you should do is tell us the error. Also, assuming it's a runtime error, use a debugger to single step the code and see where it goes wrong. Furthermore, make sure whatever is calling your function (you forgot to show that part too) is passing a writable string and not for example a string literal which is read only. PS: at `rs_exit` `eax` will point at the end of your string so you won't get much printed. Oh, and `ebx` is a callee-saved register you should preserve its value.

Comment: You've written 32-bit assembly code; are you sure the C code is also being compiled as 32 bit?

Comment: I edited my question to be more clear, you can it there. @NateEldredge. I believe there is no problem

Comment: `char *a = "Remove spaces  . ";` is read-only. Oh and one more problem in addition to all the others I already mentioned: you are not returning a pointer from your asm function.

Comment: Yes I couldn't  return a pointer, I will solve that problem later. How can I make it not read-only @Jester

Comment: For example use `char a[]`.

Comment: Another bug is that you need to add a trailing null at the new end of the string, else you'll see some garbage at the end.